# SQL query to Identify any break in the date column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am facing a peculiar issue and I think I have a solution but I don't have any way to confirm if the solution is correct.

I have a table "timesheet_data" which has "id" and "date_columnn". I need to identify who amongst the complete table has not filled the timesheet for more than 2 consecutive months considering the date_column has values populated for each fortnight (example: 2023-01-15, 2023-01-31). I have written this query to get the result and I have got all employees with the last timesheet date but that doesn't look correct. I want to know all employees that have any break in their records (more than or equal to 2 months) even if they have started recording timesheets again.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.countrynm, MAX(t1.date_column) AS last_date
FROM timesheet_data t1
LEFT JOIN timesheet_data t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
  AND DATE_DIFF(t2.date_column, t1.date_column, MONTH) = 1
LEFT JOIN timesheet_data t3
  ON t1.id = t3.id
  AND DATE_DIFF(t3.date_column, t1.date_column, MONTH) = 2
LEFT JOIN subscriber_base t4
  ON t1.id = t4.id
WHERE t2.date_column IS NULL
  AND t3.date_column IS NULL
  AND t1.date_column >= '2023-03-01' 
  AND t1.date_column <= '2023-07-01' 
  AND t1.countrynm = 'India'
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.countrynm
order by last_date desc
```

Table Format:

```
|id|name |country |date_column|
|--| --- | -------| --------- |
|1 |Sta  |India   |2023-01-15 |
|2 |Danny|India   |2023-01-31 |
|1 |Sta  |Americas|2023-01-31 |
|1 |Sta  |India   |2023-01-31 |
|3 |Edna |India   |2023-01-15 |
|3 |Edna |India   |2023-01-31 |
|3 |Edna |India   |2023-02-15 |
|3 |Edna |India   |2023-02-28 |
|3 |Edna |India   |2023-03-31 |
```

Here we can see that Edna has not filled her timesheet for the fortnight of 15th March but she continued from the fortnight of 31 March. Hence in case we are looking for a miss of 1 fortnight, her name should be the output.

In case the employee has missed any timesheet, their name would not appear in the table for that fortnight.

Comment: Hello, how does the input data looks like? Does a person that hasn't filled the timesheet for a specific date still appears in the table with a NULL value somewhere, or is there no line at all? Can you also share the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using a window function. With `lag` you can access the previous entry in the row above. `partition by` splits the table and answers this for each column `id` separately.

First we generate some data. There are the worker 1,2,3 and for each month an entry. We remove the rows with the month number matching the id of the worker to generate some holes in the dates.

Then we use the `window1` to look for each `id` individually. The previous entry by date is to search. The `lag` gives this date. Next the `date_diff` is used to calcualte the absent of the worker.

Please note that the `qualify` line is quoted out. If actived only rows which show an absend of over a month a displayed.

```sql
WITH tbl as (
  SELECT * from unnest([1,2,3]) id, unnest(generate_date_array("2022-01-01","2023-10-01",interval 1 month)) date_column
where extract(month from date_column)!= id) # remove some months for each id

SELECT 
  id,
  date_column,
  lag(date_column) over window1,
  date_diff(date_column,lag(date_column) over window1,month) as date_diff
 from tbl
# qualify date_diff>1 # Show only lines where absent is longer than one month.
 window window1 as (partition by id order by date_column)
```

Comment: this is super, does exactly what it says. thank you for explaining the code as well, really well